# How to make vim apply /var/log/messages syntax highlighting to any file called "messages" or "messages-*"?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I love vim's colorization of `/var/log/messages`, but it only works for that – the absolute filename. It doesn't work for older rotations of messages (e.g. `/var/log/messages-20120610`) or for messages files I get from other systems. How can I tweak this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When you have the file open, you can run:

```
:set filetype=messages
```

To automate this for all files called messages, put the following into `~/.vim/ftdetect/messages.vim`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *messages* :set filetype=messages
```

Comment: BRILLIANT! I'll be using "messages*", but this is *exactly* what I wanted. I love it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

add a line in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`,

```
au BufNewfile,BufRead messages-* set filetype=messages
```

Comment: Thanks for responding chris. Didn't work for me.

Comment: chris, did you mean `ftdetect.vim`?

Comment: No, `~/.vim/ftdetect/` is a directory, `~/.vim/filetype.vim`, all `au BufNewfile,BufRead ... set ft=..` can put in this file. more simple.

Comment: Using that file is not advised. Vim docs say: `:help new-filetype`
 "... In any way, it's better not to modify the $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim
file.  It will be overwritten when installing a new version of Vim."

Comment: `~/.vim/` is not `$VIMRUNTIME` system level. Will not be overwritten by new installed Vim.